# ¿Cómo mostrar en un bucle datos de este array?

Tags: laravel

En mi controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function index()
{
    $client = new CoinGeckoClient();
    $markets = $result = $client->coins()->getCoin('wozx');

    dd($markets);

    return view('project.index', compact('markets'));
}
```

Al imprimir `dd($markets)` me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo necesito acceder al elemento que se encuentra dentro del recuadro blanco `tickers` pero debo obtener los elementos que tiene este para imprimirlos con un foreach, dentro de los elementos de `tickers` hay esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento con este código:

```
public function index()
{
    $client = new CoinGeckoClient();
    $markets = $result = $client->coins()->getCoin('wozx');

    foreach($markets['tickers'] as $key => $market)
    {
        dd($market);
    };

    return view('project.index', compact('markets'));
}
```

Pero me trae solo el primero (El del índice cero (0))

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto obtenego los datos que requiero pero del primer elemento de `trackers`

```
public function index()
{
    $client = new CoinGeckoClient();
    $markets = $result = $client->coins()->getCoin('wozx');

    foreach($markets['tickers'] as $key => $market)
    {
        dd($market['market']['name']);
    };

    return view('project.index', compact('markets'));
}
```

Comment: `dd` te va a parar la ejecución. Si estás en un bucle solo te muestra un elemento. Mejor utiliza print_r o var_dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que eso te lo está haciendo porque si pones un *dd* en el *foreach*, va a entrar (y por lo tanto a parar el código) nada más recorrer el primer índice.

En lugar de poner:

```
foreach($markets['tickers'] as $key => $market)
{
    dd($market['market']['name']);
};
```

Pon algo así:

```
foreach($markets['tickers'] as $key => $market)
{
    print_r($market['market']['name']);
};
```

Comment: Gracias, pues no sé porque no lo sabía el `dd` solo imprime el primero.